# Type-C Cable : Different between Active cable, Passive Cable, EMCA

Tags: usb-device, usb-c

Please anyone help me to clarify different btw Active cable, Passive cable, EMCA.
Their definition seem difficult to understand.
Additional, in USB-TypeC Specification from usb.org:

```
Active cable :  An Electronically Marked Cable with additional electronics to
condition the data path signals.
```

So what's meaning of "electronics condition the data path signal" ? And what is its purpose?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Active cable" has "additional electronics" called "re-driver". USB 3.x signal pairs are unidirectional. When a signal propagates along a cable, it gets unevenly attenuated and loses its original shape. A re-driver takes input signal, and amplifies and shapes it up (adds de-emphasis and equilization) to correct the signal degradation over physical channel (cable's transmission line). The other channel works in opposite direction. General description can be [found in here](https://www.diodes.com/products/connectivity-and-timing/redrivers-repeaters/), and details in this [ElectronicsDesign article](http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/11-myths-about-redriver-signal-conditioning-products).

Re-driver ICs are manufactured by several companies like TI, NXP, Pericom/Diodes, [PI2EQX502 is an example](https://www.diodes.com/products/connectivity-and-timing/redrivers-repeaters/part/PI2EQX502T).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Beside, do you know how USB PD device can detect the cable is active or passive?

Comment: @sonnguyen, Power delivery protocol doesn't need to know if re-drivers are present or not, the re-drivers are for high-speed path only. PD only needs to know if the cable is strong enough to carry 5 A load. However, all the necessary information is supplied by EMCA, and several variants are defined, see https://www.pddnet.com/article/2016/06/designing-type-c-electronically-marked-cable-part-1